# Finding pH of tri-protic acid

Tags: acid-base, ph

I am studying for my final and I am given this problem:

> A solution of sodium phosphate is made from 10.5 g sodium phosphate in
>   150 mL of water. What is the pH of this solution

Given: Ka1, Ka2.

The solution says that we can simply calculate this pH with the following eqution:
$$pH=\frac{pK_{a1}+pK_{a2}}{2}$$
However this makes absolutely no sense to me, as this is the pH at the equivalence point.  What am I missing as towhy this equation can be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ## amphoteric
>
> A chemical species that behaves both as an acid and as a base is called amphoteric. This property depends upon the medium in which the species is investigated: $\ce{H2SO4}$ is an acid when studied in water, but becomes amphoteric in superacids.

from the [IUPAC goldbook](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00306.html).

---

For [ampholytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphoterism) like $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ the $\ce{pH}$ is independent on the concentration (in first approximation). Consider the reactions of that are possible:
\begin{align}\ce{
H2A-    + H3+O &~<=> H3A     + H2O  \tag1\\
H2A-    + H2O  &~<=> HA^{2-} + H3+O \tag2\\
HA^{2-} + H2O  &~<=> A^{3-}  + H3+O \tag3\\
}\end{align}

As the first approximation, we will assume that everything happening in equation $(3)$ is negligible, as is will only very little influence the concentration of $\ce{HA^{2-}}$. Therefore we can focus on the acidity constants $K_{a_1}$ of $(1)$ and $K_{a_2}$ of $(2)$:
\begin{align}
K_{a_1}  &= \frac{c(\ce{H3+O})\cdot c(\ce{H2A-})   }{c(\ce{H3A})}  \tag4\\
K_{a_2}  &= \frac{c(\ce{H3+O})\cdot c(\ce{HA^{2-}})}{c(\ce{H2A-})} \tag5\\
\end{align}
We will just go ahead and multiply these equations, since they are coupled, simultaneously happening processes. Then we will cancel whatever cancels.
\begin{align}
K_{a_1} \cdot K_{a_2} &= \frac{c(\ce{H3+O})\cdot c(\ce{H2A-})   }{c(\ce{H3A})} \cdot
  \frac{c(\ce{H3+O})\cdot c(\ce{HA^{2-}})}{c(\ce{H2A-})} \\
K_{a_1} \cdot K_{a_2} &= c^2(\ce{H3+O})\cdot  \frac{c(\ce{HA^{2-}})}{c(\ce{H3A})} \tag7\\
\end{align}
Now another major assumption is that the reactions $(1)$ and $(2)$ are happening to the same extent and therefore we can approximate
$$c(\ce{HA^{2-}})=c(\ce{H3A})\tag8$$
and rewrite $(7)$ as
\begin{align}
c^2(\ce{H3+O}) &= K_{a_1} \cdot K_{a_2}\\
c(\ce{H3+O})   &= \sqrt{K_{a_1} \cdot K_{a_2}}\\
\ce{pH}        &= \frac12\left(\mathrm{p}K_{a_1}+\mathrm{p}K_{a_2}\right).
\end{align}

However, this equation only works as a first approximation. Usually the coupled equilibria are very complex and in most instances a computer needs to be involved to calculate it accurately. More information on [polyprotic acids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_solution#Polyprotic_acids).